# Modifying and Comparing similarity of two files

Tags: awk, file-manipulation

I have 2 files. Sample values of *file1* are as follows:

```
1313 0 60
1313 1 60
1314 0 60
1314 1 57
1315 1 60
1316 0 60
1316 1 57
1317 1 57
1318 1 57
1333 0 57
1333 1 57
1334 0 60
1334 1 60
```

Sample values of *file2* are as follows:

```
813 0 91
813 1 91
814 0 91
814 1 91
815 0 96
815 1 91
816 0 91
816 1 91
817 1 96
818 0 91
832 0 96
833 0 91
833 1 91
834 0 96
```

I am trying to modify *file1* and create a *file3* with the following values (as you can see, the values in the last column of *file1* are irrelevant):

```
1 0 
1 1 
2 0 
2 1 
3 1 
4 0 
4 1 
5 1 
6 1 
21 0 
21 1 
22 0 
22 1
```

Also, the *file2* needs to be modified, and a *file4* is to be created with the following values (the values in the last column of *file2* are irrelevant):

```
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 1
3 0 
3 1
4 0
4 1
5 1
6 0
20 0
21 0
21 1
22 0
```

After the creation of *file3* and *file4*, I intend to check their similarity using the **diff** utility. To generate *file3* and *file4*, I am trying to write an `awk` script. But as a beginner to `awk`, I find the task very time consuming. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can capture the value from `$1` on the first row and then just use it in a formula to calculate the offset. This assumes the smallest `$1` is in the first row.

```
awk 'NR==1 { i=$1 } { print $1-i+1,$2 }'
```

So for example, you can do:

```
awk 'NR==1 { i=$1 } { print $1-i+1,$2 }' file1 > file3
awk 'NR==1 { i=$1 } { print $1-i+1,$2 }' file2 > file4
diff file3 file4
```

This was my previous version before I noticed you were really looking for an offset.  I had assumed you just wanted to change it based on the change in `$1`. We can set up a variable to use to check value changes between rows and only increment the counter when `$1` changes.  This assumes that are grouped.

```
awk 'n!=$1 { i++ } { print i,$2 } { n=$1 }'
```

So for example, you can do:

```
awk 'n!=$1 { i++ } { print i,$2 } { n=$1 }' file1 > file3
awk 'n!=$1 { i++ } { print i,$2 } { n=$1 }' file2 > file4
diff file3 file4
```